# Taurus Error Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, blazemeter, taurus

I am running tests using BZT using Taurus .My chrome browser version got updated to 116XX and I changed my test files to use latest deriver but till it always refer to version 114 and crash - Some how it still refers to 114 even though in logs it picked up version 116 and downloaded it .

```
modules:
  console:
    disable: true
  selenium:
    chromedriver:
      version: 116.0.5845.96
      download-link: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/win64/chrome-win64.zip chrome_version: 116.0.5845.96
```

Full Log

```
RunPerformanceTests
========================================
Running tests for pmi1
Running tests for -o settings.env.USERNAME tests/pmi1.yml
12:03:24 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.16.24
12:03:24 INFO: Starting with configs: ['C:\\Users\\elji.varughese\\.bzt-rc', 'tests/pmi1.yml']
12:03:24 INFO: Configuring...
12:03:24 INFO: Proxy settings not set
12:03:24 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\Taursu\Harmoni.Client.PerformanceMonitoring\results\pmi
12:03:24 INFO: Preparing...
12:03:24 INFO: Using StandardLocalMonitor for engine health monitoring
12:03:25 INFO: Latest stable version of chromedriver is 114.0.5735.90
12:03:25 INFO: Used version of chromedriver is 116.0.5845.96
12:03:25 INFO: Latest stable version of geckodriver is 0.33.0
12:03:25 INFO: Used version of geckodriver is 0.33.0
12:03:30 WARNING: Failed to check for updates, server returned 5xx.
12:03:30 INFO: Starting...
12:03:30 INFO: Waiting for results...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58711/devtools/browser/cadd8f09-e81e-42c4-b8a1-c7b71090ec64
12:03:39 WARNING: Please wait for graceful shutdown...
12:03:39 INFO: Shutting down...
12:03:40 INFO: Post-processing...
12:03:40 INFO: Test duration: 0:00:10
12:03:40 INFO: Samples count: 1, 100.00% failures
12:03:40 INFO: Average times: total 3.731, latency 0.000, connect 0.000
12:03:40 INFO: Percentiles:
+---------------+---------------+
| Percentile, % | Resp. Time, s |
+---------------+---------------+
|           0.0 |          3.73 |
|          50.0 |          3.73 |
|          90.0 |          3.73 |
|          95.0 |          3.73 |
|          99.0 |          3.73 |
|          99.9 |          3.73 |
|         100.0 |          3.73 |
+---------------+---------------+
12:03:40 INFO: Request label stats:
+----------------+--------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| label          | status |  succ | avg_rt | error                                                                                       |
+----------------+--------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test_dashboard |  FAIL  | 0.00% |  3.731 | Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 |
```

Comment: This issue is logged with Taurus https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus/issues/1753

Comment: I am still interested to know any workarounds